# Adding Object to collection takes long time

Tags: c#

I am creating a new Node object then adding it to a collection.

The problem is that when it hits the line of code:

```
Nodes.Add(n);
```

The debugger just sits there like the add takes forever. If i walk away and come back in 30 minutes and hit Break All it will still be adding the Node.

Any ideas why that would be happening?

```
public BindingList<vmNode> Nodes;


        private void Node_Added(BindingList<vmNode> nodes)
    {

        tvwNodes.SelectedNode.Expand();

        using (ENIEntities context = ENIEntities.ConnectToSqlServer(ENI.Data.Configuration.ConnectionString))
        {
            foreach (vmNode n in nodes)
            {
                //Do Prefix and Suffix
                //ENI.Node Node = new ENI.Node(Convert.ToInt32(tvwNodes.SelectedNode.Value));
                NodeType nt = null;

                nt = context.NodeTypes.SingleOrDefault(no => no.NodeTypeID == n.NodeTypeID);


                n.Name = (nt.Prefix ?? "") + " " + n.Name + " " + (nt.Suffix ?? "");
                Nodes.Add(n);
                //StyleNode
                StyleNode(GetAddedNode(tvwNodes.SelectedNode.Nodes, n.NodeID));
            }

        }

    }
```

Calling Code

```
        private void showAddNodeDialog(string strNodeType)
    {
        if (tvwNodes.SelectedNode != null)
        {

            Node Node = null;

            using (ENIEntities context = ENIEntities.ConnectToSqlServer(ENI.Data.Configuration.ConnectionString))
            {
                Node = context.Nodes.Find((Int32)tvwNodes.SelectedNode.Value);
            }

            frmNewNode frm = new frmNewNode(Node.NodeID, strNodeType);
            frm.NodeAdded += Node_Added;
            frm.ShowDialog();

            if (frm.copiedChildren)
            {
                LoadTree();
            }

            loadControls();

            tvwNodes.SelectedNode = GetAddedNode(tvwNodes.Nodes, Node.NodeID);
            tvwNodes.SelectedNode.Expand();
            tvwNodes.SelectedNode.EnsureVisible();

            frm.NodeAdded -= Node_Added;
            frm.Dispose();

            //frmNewDocument frm = new frmNewDocument(Convert.ToInt32(tvwNodes.SelectedNode.Value), strDocumentType);
            //frm.ShowDialog();
            //loadControls();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You Must Select a Node to Add to");
    }
```

Comment: Is `Node_Added` some kind of event handler?

Comment: Yes. Another form is loaded to create the node. When the node is created, this gets called

Comment: Is it possible that `Nodes.Add(n);` ends up calling `Node_Added` and you have a recursive call?

Comment: i added the calling code because i thought the same thing so i added a remove handler. Ill try adding a break point at the beginning of the function and see if it hits again

Comment: It doesnt hit it again nor do i see anything in the stack trace to suggest its in an infinte loop somehow. Is there another way to tell?

Comment: You don't think that the definition of `Nodes` would be at least a little bit pertinent to the question?

Comment: Task manager... Is CPU usage high for your process or do you have a hang? When you do break all... Have you looked at the other threads? Setting a break point and stepping through the code is also a good idea you should be able to see what line it gets hung up on or off it gets called repeatedly.

Comment: @MikeNakis ok added but really? thats worth a downvote? couldnt someone just ask?

Comment: @Derek Doesnt hang so i think Enigmativity may be on to something but ive set break points on all places i could find that references the tree and when i step in it just hits that line and sits there (not hangs)

The one thing im wondering though is that if it was that wouldnt i get an oom exception at some point?

Comment: you can try something like `Nodes.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;` just to see how much faster it goes

Comment: or better `Debug.Print(n.Name);` before `Nodes.Add(n);` to see if the same name is added

Comment: @Slai RaiseListChangedEvents made a huge difference. This leads me to believe Enigmativity is right and i have a recursive call somehow. Thanks

Comment: @Enigmativity adding RaiseListChangeEvents = false stops it from sitting on that call. If you want to say i have a recursive call somewhere ill accept that as the answer

Comment: @Muckeypuck someone who posts a sarcastic comment is rarely the one who downvoted.  A comment, even a sarcastic one, shows that someone cares.

Comment: If it was a recursive call problem you would probably get the name of this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `Nodes.Add(n);` ends up calling `Node_Added` and you have a recursive call.

Based on the comments to you question this is indeed what appears to have happened.